What does assign(home=1) mean in Pandas Python?
I am trying to understand what the following snippet of the code does, in particular the assign(home=1).rename part:
goal_model_data = pd.concat([epl[['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HomeGoals']].assign(home=1).rename(
            columns={'HomeTeam':'team', 'AwayTeam':'opponent','HomeGoals':'goals'}),
           epl[['AwayTeam','HomeTeam','AwayGoals']].assign(home=0).rename(
            columns={'AwayTeam':'team', 'HomeTeam':'opponent','AwayGoals':'goals'})])

This is taken from text
That deals with regression modelling in pandas. I don't exclude the possibilities of mistakes in the code snippets they provide. But when I run the code, it seems to function properly. But I don't actually understand the meaning of the above given code and how it functions.
Please help.

Looks to be creating a binary column, which will have a value of 0 for the first df and 1 for the second

pandas.DataFrame.assign

Ok, but if it's new column named "home", why doesn't the name inside assign come enclosed in quotation marks? I would expect it to be assign("home"=1), not assign(home=1)

DataFrame.assign(**kwargs), it's like doing dict(home=1) (equivalent to {"home": 1}).

So, df.assign(home=1) is equivalent to df.assign(**{"home": 1}).

That uses pd.df.assign() to add a new column with specific values. In the case of assign(home=1), it adds a column called 'home' where every row will have the value of 1.

Why isn't "home" inside assign() in quotation marks?

I'm not sure why they wrote the code that way. Please see the examples at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html
